# Can a rendered partial observe local variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a shared template that i use regularly to show errors like :

```
 <%= render "shared/flash_error", :error => flash[:error], :info => flash[:info] %>
```

This variables are optional, so my view is like :

```
<% if defined?(error) and error %>
    <div class="error">
        <%= error %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<% if defined?(info) and info %>
    <div class="info">
        <%= info %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Now, there are cases when i would need to add a new optional variable and extend the partial with other types of errors. This, however, can make the rendering hard to keep up with. I would now need to edit every render and change it to :

```
<%= render "shared/flash_error", :error => flash[:error], :info => flash[:info], :new_entry => flash[:new_entry] %>
```

and so on with every new entry. So, i am wondering, is there a way for the rendered partial to 'observe' specific flash variables,so that i don't even have to pass them as attributes to the rendered view ?

Comment: hmm, immediately after posting this, i thought that maybe passing a collection array could possibly do the trick. But i will have to check it. Weird that you sometimes get an idea right after posting a question lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap, tried it and works fine. Something like :

```
<%= render "shared/flash_error", msg_notifications %>
```

where msg_notifications is just a hash filled with everything, so it can be changed in a DRY way. Simple, yet sometimes the mind plays bad games :P